# Parsing command line argument to skip user confirmations

Tags: shell-script

If a specific argument such as "-y" or "--yes" is passed I want to make the script non-interactive and skip user confirmation. I also want to know how would I pass the argument to other scripts I source.

```
SHORT=yq
LONG=yes,quick

PARSED=$(getopt --options $SHORT --longoptions $LONG --name "$0" -- "$@")
eval set -- "$PARSED"

q=0; autoConfirm=0

while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -q|--quick)
            q=1
            shift
            ;;
        -y|--yes)
            autoConfirm=1
            shift
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid option.  Use -h for help"
            exit 3
            ;;
    esac
done

assertConfirmation () {
    local promptMsg=$1 autoConfirm=$2
    if (( autoConfirm )); then
        return
    else
        clear
        read  -n 1 -p "$promptMsg (yes/No) "
        printf '\n========================================================================'
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^([Yy])$ ]]; then
            return
        fi
    fi
    return 1
}

if assertConfirmation "Install this?" "${autoConfirm:?}"; then
    install
fi

source installation "${autoConfirm:?}" "${q:?}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your installation script expects.  To keep things simple, it is best to have it accept `-y` and `-q` as arguments.  With that, you can change your case statement so that `q` and `autoConfirm` are set to `-q` and `-y` instead of 1 (and null by default), and call your installation script as:

```
source installation $autoConfirm $q
```

With that change, use `[[ $autoconfirm ]]` to check if it is set, instead of `(( autoConfirm ))`.

Comment: They're setting `autoConfirm` to `0` at the start of the script, `(( autoConfirm ))` will check if it's nonzero. `[[ $autoConfirm ]]` would always be true, since `0` is not a null/empty string.